# What is the "payroll tax cut" as mentioned in the news recently?

Tags: united-states, taxes, news, payroll-taxes

Today I was watching news and I heard about a "payroll tax cut." They were talking about a 2 month extension of something being passed, but they wanted to pass a 1 year extension.

Can someone please explain what this payroll tax cut is exactly, and if it is going to affect my tax return in any way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Payroll Tax is the FICA deduction from you pay for 6.2% (up to the first $106,800 of wages for an individual in 2011) of income which covers your Social Security costs. In 2011, it was reduced by 2%, $1000 saved by the median $50K earning family.

Today, they voted to make the 2% reduction extended through 2012. At the high end, a family with two earners can save as much as $4272 from this temporary reduction.

Comment: thats good. They shud have extended it for one year then. :)

Comment: I'm not sure how good it is, its leaving the Social Security underfunded. The system liabilities are not being reduced.

Comment: Social Security is not underfunded. A common misconception. [Source <http://www.ssa.gov/oact/STATS/table4a3.html>](http://www.ssa.gov/oact/STATS/table4a3.html)

Comment: Not yet, but the bean counters are predicting that it will be upside-down by 2016: http://money.usnews.com/money/retirement/articles/2009/05/13/what-social-securitys-underfunding-means-for-your-retirement

Comment: The US govt can afford to pay anything, so it can never run out of money. I think that's the common misconception - that we think its different than other govt spending.

Comment: @AndyWiesendanger - Agreed, but - the concept was that it should be segregated and self funded. We think of it (incorrectly, perhaps) as insurance+pension. It's on the verge of being an underfunded pension. As far as the "can afford" part, the national debt is now scaring me. I am 49. It's only in the last year or so I've been scared.

Comment: @Asdfg Increasing or decreasing taxes is like making more or less trips to the ATM. The money doesn't magically go away if it isn't taxed, nor does more money magically appear if taxes are increased. *Spending* is the real problem. Incentives are also important, but such small and temporary changes have been shown not to affect incentives.

Comment: Social Security "fund" is an accounting gimmick - there's no separate place where the funds are stored, the taxes are mixed into general revenue and the benefits are paid from general budget. So social security can never really "run out of money" - it can become heavier and heavier burden on the budget, but the government can always print or tax more, or cut benefits. It's not an insurance or pension scheme, it is tax+welfare benefit scheme. For accounting reasons, taxes and benefits are counted as part of the "fund", but that's just accounting.